# Derek Oppen and the Nelson-Oppen combination procedure

Tags: computer-science, computer-scientists

[Derek Oppen](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=140927) was a student of Stephen Cook known for the [Nelson-Oppen combination of decision procedures method](https://www.lsi.upc.edu/%7Eoliveras/TDV/NO.pdf). Yet, there is no Wikipedia entry dedicated to him and his [publication list](https://dblp.org/pid/36/2612.html) extends during a single decade.

I was wondering if there are any references about his academic career. To be precise, I'm interested on how the collaboration between Nelson and Oppen happened. My understanding is that [Nelson](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=87404) was still a PhD student and [Oppen](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=140927) had recently graduated.

Comment: Oppen is mentioned on Greg Nelson's Wiki page.  Perhaps you could write a new Wiki page for Oppen -- might be a fun exercise.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft in fact I tried to do this in the past, however the lack of material makes it difficult to publish, my entry on another verification pioneer was rejected

Comment: According to a 26 Jan 2017 obituary in the Daily Progress (of Charlottesville, VA) Oppen died 15 Jan 2017.

Comment: https://dailyprogress.com/obituaries/oppen-derek-charles/article_2d50abdf-4e9f-5687-93d9-eeba8cd9559e.html

Comment: So they probably met at stanford